# Moving position of CMV Home Button?

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

I'm relatively new at working with the CMV (and .css).

What's the easiest way to change the Home button's position?

To clarify, I'm attempting to move the position of the button itself down about 100px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *really* should be done via css in a css file. However the CMV html template for the map controls is a bit dated and so not as easy to reposition as the positioning is done directly in the template. I will add updating this approach as a to-do item for the next version of the cmv core application

In the meantime, you can accomplish what you want by changing [line 13](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/blob/master/viewer/js/viewer/templates/mapOverlay.html#L13) in the template. To move it down 100px, change `top:94px` to `top:194px`. This will also move down the locate button if you are using that.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that.  I figured out a way to move it by downloading/copying the esri.css file and changing the property within the .HomeButton.home element, but this method is a lot easier.  Thanks!